# How to enable Swagger UI in Azure Easy API

Tags: node.js, azure, swagger, azure-mobile-services, swagger-ui

I'm using Azure App Services and have setup the Easy API with Easy Table for the API backend for my mobile.

I was wondering how can I setup the Swagger UI for the Azure App Service.

When I try to navigate to the API (e.g. https://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui), it is stated that "To access the swagger UI, you must enable swagger support by adding swagger: true to your configuration and installing the swagger-ui npm module"

How do you exactly add the swagger-ui npm when you don't have the source to the API (it's created automatically using Easy API) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two parts to your question:

1) Enabling Swagger on EasyAPI is not possible right now.  That is to say, we don't merge nor generate the Swagger for EasyAPI as all the parameters are defined in code.

2) If you want to enable Swagger, then you need to add 'swagger: true' to the initializer for Azure Mobile Apps in the app.js file at the level above your API.  Go into Easy API or Easy Tables and edit any API/Table.  This will bring up the editor.  Go to the directory above (the one that contains the api and tables directories) and edit the app.js file there.

Comment: I have added the swagger: true in the app.js but the result using above url to swagger yield the same result. I wonder if we need to add the swagger-ui npm as it is not there in the node_module folder?

Comment: @daniel Yes, you can deploy the module via Git repository, or run the npm install commond on App Service Editor. You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/ for details.

Comment: After cloning the git repository to local and add swagger-ui in the package.json, it can now run the swagger. Thanks !

Comment: @daniel how did you do that, can you show the complete package file

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. On Portal Azure
2. Open your-application App Service
3. Go to Development Tools -> App Service Editor (Preview) - click GO
4. **Inside** App Service Editor (Preview) -> Open **Console** ( CTRL + Shift + C )
5. Type **npm install --save swagger-ui**
6. Waiting install
7. Check install if exists folder on node_modules -> swagger-ui
8. Now enable swagger on application file /wwwroot/app.js

Change content:

var mobile = azureMobileApps({
    // Explicitly enable the Azure Mobile Apps home page
    homePage: true,

```
// Explicitly enable swagger support. UI support is enabled by
// installing the swagger-ui npm module.
swagger: true
```

});

9. Test Swagger on https://your-application.azurewebsites.net on Google Chrome click **try it out** or open https://your-application.azurewebsites.net**/swagger/ui**